# Python nmap not showing hosts

Tags: python, security, ip, host, nmap

This is the code:

```
import nmap
# initialize the port scanner
nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()

# scan localhost for ports in range 21-443
nmScan.scan('89.43.3.92', '20-450')

# run a loop to print all the found result about the ports
print(nmScan.all_hosts())
for host in nmScan.all_hosts():
     print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nmScan[host].hostname()))
     print('State : %s' % nmScan[host].state())
     for proto in nmScan[host].all_protocols():
         print('----------')
         print('Protocol : %s' % proto)
 
         lport = nmScan[host][proto].keys()
        #  lport.sort()
         for port in lport:
             print ('port : %s\service : %s' % (port, nmScan[host][proto][port]['name']))
```

When I use 127.0.0.1, the code works fine and `nmScan.all_hosts()` is not empty, but when I check other ip addresses, it always is empty.

P.S: In the code above, I'm trying to see what service each port is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a VPN, turn it off. This solved my problem.